# Listing files with size greater than N

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I need to list all files with size > 0 under a directory (where it's actually expected that the file size is 0). How can I do it with grep and/or awk? I was thinking of something like

```
$ ls -alR | grep ... | awk ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yet another `find` option:

```
find . ! -empty
```

update: (thanks to @steve comment)

If you need to list only files in only current directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -empty
```

Note that `-maxdepth` is GNU feature. In POSIX environment there is another way:

```
find -type f -o \( ! -name . -type d -prune -false \) ! -empty
```